# Python 3.10 Error Installing Packages via CMD

Tags: python

*Using Python 3.10, Windows 10, CMD "pip installer" command*

---

Greetings :)

whilst installing most python packages . . .
currently using CMD to install using "pip" command.
i keep receiving a

> note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
> metadata-generation-failed output

`any idea what this could be ?`

---

thanks for reading and cheers, ☕

Attempted resolve, by downgrading from 3.11 to 3.10,
seemingly no difference.

---

checked
C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\Lib\site-packages

packages i installed are there,
yet pycharm IDE isnt using them

most likely an older version of python is the solution ???

???

Comment: what are the packages you are trying to install? which python/pip version? whar is the environement?

Comment: also please include the full output of pip

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: @Farid Fakhry , Greetings. 
So far, i have been Attempting to install GUI Libraries, such as :
> DearPyGui